# Add button to toolbar in wpf programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, button, browser

I'm trying to add a bookmark function to my browser but I can't figure out how to add my created button to the toolbar.

My toolbar defined in XAML:

```
<ToolBar x:Name="Bookbar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="799" Height="36">

        </ToolBar>
```

And the c# code where I try to add the created button to my toolbar:

```
private void Bookmark_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //add bookmark
    {
        if (Urlbox.Text.Contains("http://") == false)
        {
            bookmarks = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please insert your new bookmark", "New Bookmark", "http://" + Urlbox.Text);

        }
        else
        {
            bookmarks = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please insert your new bookmark", "New Bookmark", Urlbox.Text);
        }



        Button book1 = new Button();
        book1.Content = "Test";
        book1.Click += Button_Click;
        Bookbar.Children.Add(book1);

    }
```

I'm recieving

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Controls.ToolBar' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no extension method 'Children' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ToolBar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

on the line 'Bookbar.Children.Add(book1);'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you receiving ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, added that to the main post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not `BookBar.Children.Add()` it should be `BookBar.Items.Add`